# Finding the eigenvectors of an arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Im asked to find the eigenvectors of the arbitrary matrix where $a\neq d$
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a\ \ \ b
\\0\ \ \ d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I know the eigenvalues are $a,d$ but when I compute the null space of the matrix $(A-aI)$ I end up with:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ b \ |\ 0
\\0\ \ \ d-a|\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$h
I don't understand how to get the eigenvectors from this. I thought a cant equal d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $d\neq a
 $ we get $d-a\neq0
 $ therefore:

> $\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
> 0 & b & | & 0\\
> 0 & d-a & | & 0
> \end{array}\right]\to\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
> 0 & b & | & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & | & 0
> \end{array}\right]\to\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
> 0 & 0 & | & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & | & 0
> \end{array}\right]
>  $.

What "really" happened here was:
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & b & | & 0\\
0 & d-a & | & 0
\end{array}\right]
 $ means we are trying to find $v=\left[\begin{array}{c}
v_{0}\\
v_{1}
\end{array}\right]
 $ s.t. $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & b\\
0 & d-a
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
v_{0}\\
v_{1}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]
 $.
This means $\left.\begin{cases}
0\cdot v_{0}+b\cdot v_{1} & =0\\
0\cdot v_{0}+\left(d-a\right)\cdot v_{1} & =0
\end{cases}\right|\Longrightarrow\left.\begin{cases}
b\cdot v_{1} & =0\\
\left(d-a\right)\cdot v_{1} & =0
\end{cases}\right|
 $.
Since $d\neq a
 $ we can divide the second equation by $\left(d-a\right)
 $ and get $v_{1}=0.
 $
We can now choose any $v_{0}\neq0
 $ to satisfy $A\left[\begin{array}{c}
v_{0}\\
v_{1}
\end{array}\right]=a\left[\begin{array}{c}
v_{0}\\
v_{1}
\end{array}\right]
 $ as these eignvectors are linearly dependant and give us the same null space.